# Subgroup that intersects all conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $H$ intersects all conjugacy classes of $G$ non trivially. Then proof that $H=G$.

I have no clear idea how to attempt this except that $H$ contains atleast one element of each possible order. And I think that $G$ being finite has something to do in the proof. But I am not able to proceed.

Comment: And [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93064/a-subgroup-intersects-every-conjugacy-class) are some counterexamples for the case where $G$ is infinite.

Comment: Thank you @lulu